# HTML5 History API Requires Double Back Clicks

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, html5-history

I'm tying to implement pagination with ajax and the HTML5 history API. Let me describe the sequence of events to explain my problem.

I have the following 4 pagination pages.

1 - 2 - 3 - 4

Here is the sequence of stuff that happens.

- Open page
- Click '2' // All Good
- Click '3' // All Good
- Click '4' // All Good
- Click Chrome Browser Back Button // Goes to page 3, All Good
  **- Click Chrome Browner Back Button // Stays at page 3.
- Quickly double click the back button // Goes to page 2**

I can't figure out why double back clicks gives the desired outcome, but 1 back click doesn't work. Here is my code simplified.

```
function fetch(val) {
  var page = val;

  // Ajax Request Code

  success: function (data) {
     // Some processing code
     window.history.pushState(page, '', '/mydata/page-num-' + page);

  },

  // Other Ajax Request Code

}

window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    fetch(parseInt(event.state))
};
```

The value passed to my fetch function is just an integer. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed my problem.

The problem going from 4 -> 3 was that the call to 'fetch function' from 'onpopstate' should not result in a pushState. The reason double click was working was because 'onopopstate' was getting executed twice before the pushState had a chance to overwrite.